# Using DateFormatter getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2, works fine in playground Swift

Tags: swift, date, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to convert a string that contains a time and date stamp in the format like this "02/03/19 11:00:00", I'm able to use DateFormatter to convert it to a Date format in playground fine, but as soon as I try to use the code in my project it throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The function that I'm using is as follows

```
 func convertStringToDate(dateString : String) -> Date {
    var theDate : Date = Date.init()
    print(dateString)
    let theDateFormat = DateFormatter()
    theDateFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_AU")
    theDateFormat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy' 'HH:mm:ss"
    theDateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    theDate = theDateFormat.date(from: dateString) ?? Date.init()
    return theDate
}
```

I'm just hoping that someone may have a couple of ideas that I can try to get past this roadblock.

Comment: Try `dd/MM/yy` and change the formatter locale to en_US_POSIX. Btw there is no need to escape the space

Comment: Thanks changing en_AU to en_US_POSIX worked. Just curious as to why having it at en_AU would fail?

Comment: Off topic but I think your function should return an optional date (`Date?`) or throw an error, returning todays date if the formatting fails hides a potential bug or can lead to trouble further on. Better to let the calling code decide what to do if the formatting fails